# Good datatypes to have for QueryParameter Javabean

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

**My question is**: What are the datatypes I should support for a Javabean to fill a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)?

I'm writing a SQLHelper for a [Java Helper Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper). One of the classes I'm writing is a `QueryParameter` Javabean which holds a type and value. It's main use is to be associated with a `HelperQuery` Javabean and a prepared statement will be filled with them in a call like this to the following method:

`fillStatement(preparedStatement, helperQuery.getParams());`

```
public void fillStatement(PreparedStatement pstmt, QueryParameter... params) throws SQLException {
  for (int i = 1; i <= params.length; i++) {
    QueryParameter param = params[i - 1];
    switch (param.getType()) {
      case QueryParameter.CLOB:
        pstmt.setClob(i, (Clob) clob);
        break;
      case QueryParameter.STRING:
        pstmt.setString(i, (String) param.getValue());
        break;
      case QueryParameter.YOU_GET_THE_IDEA:
        //...;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) javadoc and support every `setSomething` datatype there. They are:

```
Array, AsciiStream, BigDecimal, BinaryStream, Blob, Boolean, Byte,
Bytes, CharacterStream, Clob, Date, Double, Float, Int, Long,
NCharacterStream, NClob, NString, Null, Object, Ref, RowId, Short,
SQLXML, String, Time, Timestamp, and URL
```

Comment: Halfway through asking my question I realized the answer was simple :)